# Understanding the effect of HPF on the amplitude and phase control in STM32

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, control, pid-controller

I am using a STM32 to control amplitude and phase of a signal when passed through a RC circuit(LPF) which later will be replaced with a tip tilt mirror.

I have a STM32 which has the code implemented. (DDS for signal generation + amplitude control + phase control) First the signal generated is passed through the RC circuit (first order LPF with cut off 3-4 kHz, R1 = 1K, C1 = 44 nF) and read back the signal to first measure the amplitude using RMS method and then phase detection using multiplier phase detection. My sampling rate is 50 kHz and signal FRE is 1 kHz, ADC and DAC resolution is 12 bit. DDS generation is through LUT saved in the MCU. The amplitude and phase readings are slightly fluctuating especially the phase but I assume it's because of the timer interrupt in STM not being super precise. So far good. After turning on the controller, the fluctuations are slightly more within few mV and less than 1 deg range for fluctuation but acceptable range. Now, I add HPF after the circuit and read in the STM (because I need HPF for the mirror setup_), the signals are fluctuating even more. The ADC reading is within the tolerance but the phase is fluctuating around 5 deg diff. I am wondering what could have lead to this. I see higher frequency noise in FFT and assume it to be the reason but I thought the integrator in phase detection part should remove the high frequency noise, no?
The theta output after control reaching set value. (Should have been stable.)

[image: theta]

[image: DDS]

[image: control]

For the amplitude control I have used integral part only and for phase, proportional loop. But the problem lies before I turn the control on when I use HPF.

FFT from the controlled signal/DDS:

[image: dds]

From RC circuit/system:

[image: adc]

From HPF:

[image: hpf]

My SNR value is 8.24, 10.96 and 45.19 respectively.

I don't think the code is wrong else it wouldn't have worked in for the case without the HPF. I am wondering if and how does the HPF affect the measurement? If the code is necessary, will upload it later. Could anyone help me with?